# How to dynamically import a module in Javascript / ReactJs / React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to dynamically import a module from a path **`importPath`** set via **Props**.

```
var importPath;

class MainComponent extends Component {
    state = {}
    render() {
        // Set var importPath = "path_to_module here;"
        // importPath = this.props.myModulePath
        return (
            <ComponentToImport myComponentPath="./ToastExample" />);
    }
}

export default MainComponent;
```

**Then :**

```
class ComponentToImport extends Component {
    ToastExample: (async () => {
        await import (this.props.revPath)
    })()

    async sayHiFromJava() {
        this.state.ToastExample.showJ('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT);
    }

    render() {
        return (<ToastExample />);
    }
}
```

How can I go about this?

Thank you all in advance.

How do I attach `ToastExample` in `import ToastExample from importPath;` to `await import("importPath");` so that I can `return(<ToastExample />);`

**UPDATE**

I have tried :

```
class ComponentToImport extends Component {
    ToastExample: (async () => {
        await import (this.props.revPath)
    })()

    async sayHiFromJava() {
        this.state.ToastExample.showJ('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT);
    }

    render() {
        return (<ToastExample />);
    }
}
```

but I get the error :

```
error: bundling failed: index.js: index.js:Invalid call at line 28: import(_this.props.myComponentPath)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is the way:

```
import("importPath").then(() => {
    // your code
});
```

or

```
await import("importPath");

// your code
```

see more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: How do I attach `ToastExample` in `import ToastExample from importPath;'' to `await import("importPath");` so that I can `return(<ToastExample />);`

Comment: I tried that but I get an `error: bundling failed: index.js: index.js:Invalid call at line 28: import(_this.props.revPath)`. Any suggestions? I did an update to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Is it what your are looking for?

```
const ToastExample = await import('importPath');
```

**EDIT**: Please read the official doc to set up your webpack or Babel (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

```
class ComponentToImport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { module: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { path } = this.props;
    import(`${path}`).then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }));
  }
  render() {
    const { module: Component } = this.state;
    return <div>{Component && <Component />}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an `error: bundling failed: index.js: index.js:Invalid call at line 28: import(_this.props.revPath)`. Any suggestions? I did an update to the question.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply, but how do I attach `ToastExample` in `import ToastExample from importPath;` to `await import("importPath");` so that I can `return(<ToastExample />);`

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev by passing the "<ToastExample />" path to this component, you are returning your "<ToastExample />" but it is named "<Component />".

Answer (score -2):

If you want to pass component to child component one way is to  pass through child props.

```
import myComponentPath from "./ToastExample"
<ComponentToImport>
  <myComponentPath />
<ComponentToImport/>
```

and then

```
class ComponentToImport extends Component {
    render() {
        return (this.props.children);
    }
}
```

May be this helps.

Thanks