# Why is await import(pathVariable) not working whilst await import('./file.json') works fine? pathVariable contains the same string

Tags: javascript, import

I am trying to load a json dynamically based on a string variable, however, when I try to use even the most basic variable that contains a string, I get an error, whereas when I use the string it works just fine

```
const configLoader = async () => {
    const pathVariable = './file.json';
    const fileName = 'file';

    const configFile = await import('./file.json'); // Works!
    const configFile = await import(pathVariable); // Doesn't work!
    const configFile = await import(`./${fileName}.json`); // Doesn't work!
}
```

The error

```
Invalid call at line 34: import(pathVariable)
```

Comment: _"I get an error"_ - it's helpful to include the error itself as part of a [mre]. I believe static and dynamic imports are required to be fixed strings so they can be analysed statically (e.g. per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) _"Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed"_ for the module name).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm kinda confused now, what is dynamic about this import if I can't actually pass a variable string based on some computation that I make?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I forgot to add the error.

Comment: Under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports it does say you might use this _"When the import specifier string needs to be constructed dynamically."_ What's actually throwing that error - is it a bundler like Webpack that needs to resolve all of the relevant files at bundling time rather than runtime? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60562457/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59341858/3001761.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a tool, such as WebPack, which resolves imports at build-time.

It require that you pass string literals since the value of variables generally can't be known until run-time.

See [WebPack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import):

> Dynamic expressions in import()
>
> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as
> import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in
> your system or project.
>
> The import() must contain at least some information about where the
> module is located. Bundling can be limited to a specific directory or
> set of files so that when you are using a dynamic expression - every
> module that could potentially be requested on an import() call is
> included. For example, import(./locale/${language}.json`) will cause
> every .json file in the ./locale directory to be bundled into the new
> chunk. At run time, when the variable language has been computed, any
> file like english.json or german.json will be available for
> consumption.
>
> ```
> // imagine we had a method to get language from cookies or other storage
> const language = detectVisitorLanguage();
> import(`./locale/${language}.json`).then((module) => {
>   // do something with the translations
> });
> ```

Comment: Would the example you've given work? I tried doing the same thing but got the same error. Anything that is not a string just gives me error.

Comment: @Bobimaru — I'm just quoting the documentation. I can't see your attempt at following it and I don't know what error message you received.

Comment: I tried const configFile = await import(`./${fileName}.json`); and got the same error - Invalid call at line 31: import("./" + fileName + ".json")